# AWS CHIME SDk for javascript join a meeting through link

Tags: javascript, aws-sdk, aws-chime-sdk

i need to make a link throug which one can join the meeting. I'm currently using the demo sample of **AWS chime SDK** for javascript. 
or
if I can use the meeting ID to let the participants use it to join the meeting..

Comment: I'm actually trying to do something similar. Any luck?

Comment: not a particular solution but passing parameter with the URL and using in the meetingv2.ts instead of fetching it from the form submission helped me and while the page appear I have change the form element to **display:none** and shown only progress bar

Comment: So you actually need the front end SDK to accomplish this? I thought by only creating the meeting would give you all you need?

Comment: yup because aws doesn't support much in that... You can try https://github.com/aws/amazon-chime-sdk-js/tree/master/demos/singlejs this too

Comment: @PHPbuddy your link you posted is broken, now there are just browser and serverless in those demos